# Laravel : Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter::validMac() must be of the type array,

Tags: encryption, laravel-5.5

i am getting below error on laravel 5.5

Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter::validMac() must be of the type array, null given, called in C:\wamp64\www\projectx\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter.php on line 194

How can i solve this issue? plz help me.

Comment: You need to post the relevant code along with an explanation of what you have tried already if you expect anyone to be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

It's working after composer update command.